# The UI doesn't renew itself when I'm deleting the images from firebase storage even if I use Stream

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage, stream-builder

[image: Example]

## Code:

## View:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
        stream: context
            .read<DetailedCategoriesViewModel>()
            .listOfImages(widget.filePath),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            length = snapshot.data!.length;
            print("ilk stream çalıştı");

            final images = snapshot.data;

            return Scaffold(
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                  child: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo_rounded,
                      color: Colors.white),
                  onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context, builder: (context) => buildSheet())),
              appBar:
                  AppBar(centerTitle: true, title: Text(widget.categoryName)),
              body: RefreshIndicator(
                onRefresh: refresh,
                child: GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
                      parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
                  itemCount: images!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    imageLinks = snapshot.data!;
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.5),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: ((_) => PhotoViewPage(
                                        index: index,
                                        filePath: widget.filePath,
                                      ))));
                        },
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                          imageUrl: snapshot.data![index],
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(
                            color: Colors.red.shade400,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
 else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(centerTitle: true, title: Text("Yetki Gerekli")),
                body: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()))));
          } else {
            return const Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
```

## ViewModel

```
final _firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

Stream<List<String>> listOfImages(String path) async* {
    final listResult = await _firebaseStorage.ref(path).listAll();
    List<String> imagesList = [];
    List<Reference> files = listResult.items;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      imagesList.add(await _firebaseStorage
          .ref(path)
          .child(files[i].name)
          .getDownloadURL());
    }
    yield imagesList;
  }
```

I used futurebuilder before this and encountered this issue then change it to streambuilder but it acts like same. I watched the videos on youtube they don't use firebase storage they store the urls on firestore and get it using firestore but isn't that the same?

not only deleting , when the screen is open ı try to upload image manually on firebase still nothing.